# Regex to find any 1 or more instance of the following characters strings & | >= | " | * | ? | [ | ] | (double spaces) |

Tags: regex, oracle

Trying to do some data clean up in a database and we need to remove these characters from some text columns in the database. Need to find all the rows with any of these characters then I will replace them and send them over to the data team to re-insert with the desired replacements supplied by users

```
regexp_like (DESCRIPTION, '&|*|>=|;|?|  |[|]')
```

Wound up just returning every row in the table

This is an oracle database

need to find any of the following in a text field in the database:

```
&
*
>=
;
?
(double spaces)
[
]
```

Comment: This should match the characters inside a row signaling it is to be changed:
```(&|\*|>=|;|\?|  |\[|\])```
It only matches the characters, not the entire string though

Comment: If Oracle may I suggest `(\&|\*|>=|;|\?|  |\|)`.  Note the pipe symbols are logical ORs when used inside a group. The backslash removes the special meaning of a character to the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters that have special regex meaning (in your case the chars `"*?|[]"`) using `\`:

```
regexp_like (description, '&|\*|;|\?|\[|\]|  |\||>=')
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9dde87dad64b90df157de16ac466354c).

Or put the single characters within a character class, in which most characters lose their special regex meaning and so don't need to be escaped:

```
regexp_like (description, '[&*;?|[]|]|  |>=')
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=34d1ab9b4198cac477af99a13573e39c).

---

Putting an escaped `]` inside the character class

```
regexp_like (description, '[&*;?|[\]]|  |>=')
```

*should* work (it works in every regex flavor I've used), but doesn't work with Oracle .